# NoClassDefFoundError for inner class upon trying to enter main

Tags: java, ant, noclassdeffounderror

I've got a fairly simple program, built by ant using a basic jar task.  This task was copied and modified from an existing task in the build.xml file for another program which works fine.  The new task looks something like this:

```
<jar jarfile="${dist.dir}/CheckSiteProperties.jar">
   <fileset dir="${class.dir}">
      <include name="path/to/class/CheckSiteProperties.class" />
   </fileset>
   <manifest>
      <attribute name="Main-Class" value="path.to.class.CheckSiteProperties"/>
      <attribute name="Class-Path" value="CheckSiteProperties.jar" />
   </manifest>
</jar>
```

When I try to run the program using:

```
java -jar CheckSiteProperties.jar
```

I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: path/to/class/CheckSiteProperties$__CLR3_1_116gfw6gfwhi29d0u9
    at path.to.class.CheckSiteProperties.main(CheckSiteProperties.java:29)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: path.to.class.CheckSiteProperties$__CLR3_1_116gfw6gfwhi29d0u9
```

Line 29 in CheckSiteProperties.java contains the opening brace for the main method.

It looks to me like __CLR3_1_116gfw6gfwhi29d0u9 is some kind of inner class which is auto-generated (I haven't written any inner classes into the code) and which is presumably somehow woven at the join point of entering the main method, but I don't understand why any such inner class would not be found if the class itself is obviously found.

FWIW, if I run the code from within eclipse, no problem occurs, so eclipse seems to be providing some extra glue that is missing when building with ant and running the jar file.

Comment: Is there any reason not to just include everything from your ${class.dir} in the jar?  Look in there, see if your __CLR3_1_116gfw6gfwhi29d0u9 class exists.

Comment: Correct; inner classes are in separate class files after compilation.

Comment: I can't include the entire ${class.dir} -- it contains other program classes as well. For whatever reason, I'd not previously noticed that inner classes created separate .class files in the classes folder. (I will definitely remember that for the future!)  So I was able to change the include to look for CheckSiteProperties*.class to pick up inner classes. (I also discovered the inner class was being created due to some earlier experimentation with clover for code coverage, which I don't want in the shipped code anyway, so when I turn off clover in the build, the inner class goes away as well.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since inner classes get generated to separate .class files, you'll need to include everything under your `${class.dir}` in the jar.  Just drop the `<include>` line from your code snippet.